# Rails 3 & i18n: "Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I am trying to translate my Rails 3 application, read the primer at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats and subsequently downloaded the corresponding yml file from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale (`de.yml` in my case).

In one of my views I had this code (`some_model#index`) ...

```
<td><%= time_ago_in_words(some_model.created_at) %></td>
```

... which I changed in ...

`<td><%=l time_ago_in_words(some_model.created_at) %></td>`.

Unfortunately this gives me this error:

```
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "etwa ein Monat" given.
```

Any idea why this fails? The `created_at` column has been created in the database via standard Rails scaffolding (database is mysql using mysql2 gem).

If I strip the `time_ago_in_words` helper from the code ...

`<td><%=l some_model.created_at %></td>`.

... the translation works - but the datetime now is of course too long for my `<td>`.

I also tried to duplicated the `distance_in_words` section of the `de.yml` and rename it to `time_ago_in_words` but this did not work either.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Errr ... I ... am ... a bit ... confused: After writing the initial post, I ended up reverting the relevant code block to `<td><%= time_ago_in_words(some_model.created_at) %></td>` again and hoping for an answer here. Without the `<%=l` the translation suddenly works. o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are 2 different methods in play here :

1. the `l` method takes a Date, a Time or a DateTime object and returns a formatted version based on your I18n rules.
2. the `time_ago_words` takes the same arguments and uses I18n to spit out a formatted string.

In your example, you're trying to use both! Put simply, all you need is `<%= time_ago_in_words(some_model.created_at) %>`.